# Convert array column to struct with indices from static list in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with an array column. The arrays always have the same length, e.g. like this:

**Input df**:

| col1 |
| --- |
| ["a", "b", "c"] |
| ["d", "e", "f"] |

I would like to convert the dataframe into the following with indices from a static list:

`keys = [1, 1.5, 2]`

**Desired output df**:

| col1 | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| ["a", "b", "c"] | {1: "a", 1.5: "b", 2: "c"} |
| ["d", "e", "f"] | {1: "d", 1.5: "e", 2: "d"} |

*note*: I'm looking for a solution written in PySpark and I'm using Spark version 3.3.0

I have tried different versions with struct, create_map and expr, but none come very close to what I'm trying to achieve.

The end goal is to be able to query the values in the new_column using a specific key.

Something similar to this: df.select(col('new_column').getItem(key))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `map_from_arrays`.

`Example`

```
df.withColumn("col1", expr("map_from_arrays(array(1.0, 1.5, 2.0), col1)"))
```

`Output`

```
+------------------------------+
|col1                          |
+------------------------------+
|{1.0 -> a, 1.5 -> b, 2.0 -> c}|
+------------------------------+
```

Then you can use the following expression to fetch a key from the map:

```
corrected.select(col("col1").getItem("1.0"))
```

which gives:

```
+---------+
|col1[1.0]|
+---------+
|a        |
+---------+
```

Good luck!